# Correct way to start Meditation and Fitness Exercise

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, workout, exercise-technique, yoga

I have browsed many questions but didn't find answers to my queries. Anyways, here is my very straightforward question to all experts and community members here.

I'm 27 and just started doing exercise and meditation early morning. Since, I do not have any specific routine of meditation and fitness exercises so far but what I have just framed is this:

1. First, Walking/Jogging for 10-15 minutes.
2. Then, Meditation for 10-15 minutes.
3. Finally, some squash, push-ups, jumping jacks, and other similar workouts.

However, I don't know whether this will be the correct way or not. The purpose is to increase stamina with strength, build abs, improve overall body posture and increase concentration and peace of mind.

Please guide me from your experience and knowledge. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Dear @Raditz_35, forget about the chakras. Because, chakras is not a main goal for me. But, a fit body with increased stamina and abs building for grooming overall body posture is a must goal for me.

Comment: very important point is -- Don't mix mind exercises with physical workout. Both the workouts should be at different timing. (or take 1/2 an hour gap in between both.

Answer (score 1):

**Swap meditation and jogging and you are fine.**

Jogging will increase your heart rate and improve blood flow. Therefore it is best done before exercise as warm up or after as cool down if the exercise was intense.

Meditation can either be done before when having a lower heart rate to relax and mentally prepare yourself or afterwards as cooldown when combined with stretching (yoga?).

Answer (score 0):

Mediation is best done in the morning.
(Most people who meditate will agree on this).

Walking before is common on retreats (Before long meditations), but not so much before short sessions.

Jogging before sounds like a bad idea.

As maintaining a regular  meditation habit is difficult, you should focus on what makes it easy.  (Play around with walking before or not)

Answer (score 0):

I just did this for the first time today.  It ties breathing, core stability and movement prep *(Not an exact answer but I found it really helpful and think you may)*.

Pretty eye opening how big of a difference something so seemingly small makes..

---

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN4Gni7oqq4
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwxlsUdyu8c

---